# ItemAdd events not triggered on shared calendar

Tags: c#, outlook, calendar, vsto

I have created a vsto outlook plugin. The basic idea is listen to the calendar events, and when certain events happen we have to sync to another data source.

Everything works as aspected with the user his own calendars, but as soon as we start working with shared calendars(exchange), the events aren't triggered anymore.

I have following code, it's a slimmed down version of the real plugin.

```
   CalendarModule calModule = (CalendarModule)this.Application.ActiveExplorer().NavigationPane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(OlNavigationModuleType.olModuleCalendar);
        string debug = string.Empty;
        foreach (NavigationGroup group in calModule.NavigationGroups)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= group.NavigationFolders.Count - 1; i++)
            {

                try
                {
                    NavigationFolder navFolder = group.NavigationFolders[i];
                    debug += navFolder.DisplayName + "\r";

                    Folder f = navFolder.Folder as Folder;
                    AddEventToAppointmentFolder(f);
                    debug += f.Name + "\r";
                    FolderList.Add(f);
                    Items items = f.Items;

                    debug += items.Count.ToString() + "\r";
                    AddEventsToAppointmentFolderItems(items);
                    FolderItemsList.Add(items);

                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    debug += "Error in Other foldergroup:\r" + ex.Message + "\r";
                }
            }
public void AddEventToAppointmentFolder(Folder f)
    {
        //f.BeforeItemMove += new MAPIFolderEvents_12_BeforeItemMoveEventHandler(AppointmentFolder_BeforeItemMove);
    }


    public void AddEventsToAppointmentFolderItems(Items i)
    {
        i.ItemAdd += new ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(CalendarFolderItemAdd);
        i.ItemChange += new ItemsEvents_ItemChangeEventHandler(appointments_ItemChange);
        //i.ItemRemove += new ItemsEvents_ItemRemoveEventHandler(appointments_ItemDelete);
    }
```

Has anyone any clues/suggestions how to fix this problem?

And following line throws an exception with the shared calendars.

```
Folder f = NavigationFold.Folder as Folder;

"at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NavigationFolder.get_Folder()
at OutlookAddIn1.Addin.GetSharedGroups()
```

Also if we added a shared calendar with delegation rights, and moved in to my calendars, it seemed to work. But as soon the Calendar is in a seperated directory the error reoccurs.

Anyone any ideas how to fix this?

Regards

Comment: What is the exact error?